# ODBC connection successfully but test DSN crash

Tags: odbc, mariadb, dsn

I am trying to connect a mariaDB on my server via my local computer, here are the frature and the questions:

-database name: mariaDB

-database version:5.5.44-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

-client: win 7 64bit

-server: centaOS 6.6

=========================================================

Questions:

I already install mariaODBC in my client, and the DSN test is ok too.
 [image: http://i.imgur.com/p4pPUZu.png]
But after I click the ok to finish testing DSN, the ODBC administrator crash.
[image]

what's the problem here?

Comment: What is the symptom?